# Pipe vs. Temporary File

Tags: pipe, temporary-files

Is there a big performance difference between:

- Process A writing to a temp file, and process B reading that file
- Process A writing to a pipe, and process B reading from that pipe

I'm curious to know what the answer is for both Windows and *nix.

EDIT: I should have asked: Does the buffer cache eliminate the difference between a temp file and a pipe?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

One big difference is that with the pipe, processes A and B can be running concurrently, so that B gets to work on the output from A before A has finished producing it.  Further, the size of the pipe is limited, so A won't be able to produce vastly more data than B has consumed; it will be made to wait for B to catch up.

If the volume of data is big, then writing to the temporary file involves disk activity, even if only for creating and then destroying the file.  The data might well stay in the in-memory buffer pools - so no disk I/O there - even for surprisingly large files.  Writing to the pipe 'never' involves writing to disk.

Comment: +1 - The only thing you don't explicitly answer is, is this the same for Windows and Unix.  (I doubt there would be a difference, but it was in the original question.)

Comment: @OverZealous: fair point.  My answer applies more reliably to Unix than Windows.  Windows sometimes achieves roughly the same result slightly differently from Unix, but I think my points are valid on Windows.  I am less sure that a Windows pipe never involves writing to disk.

Comment: _One big difference is that with the pipe, processes A and B can be running concurrently, so that B gets to work on the output from A before A has finished producing it._ The same can be achieved with the file as a mean of data exchange so this advantage is not unique to pipe.

Answer (score 13):

The big difference is that the first method actually uses on-disk storage, whereas a pipe will use memory (unless you get really pedantic and start thinking about swap space).

Performance-wise, memory is faster than disk (almost always). This should be generally true for all operating systems.

The only time when using a temp file really makes sense is if process B has to examine the data in multiple passes (like certain kinds of video encoding). For this use, the whole data stream would need to be buffered and if there were enough data yes it would probably negate the in-memory advantage. So for multi-pass (seek-bound) operations, go with a temp file.

Comment: See, I was wondering whether the disk cache would eliminate the difference between pipes and a temp file.

Comment: The big issue is this: while process A is writing to a *file*, process B won't be doing anything (until it's done). While process A is writing to a *pipe*, process B can immediately begin reading from it. So even if the OS did cache the whole file, you'd still have to wait until A was done. And yes, it is possible to "stream" a file (like tail -f does) but you still have to wait for A to flush before you'll see anything. So again, use a pipe unless you need to do seeks.

Comment: @Chris I dont think that process B has to wait untill process A has flushed to the file. If process B starts reading the file even before the process A has finished, nothing bad happens. process B's request will be fulfilled from the buffer itself. It need not wait until the changes are committed to the disk. Or am I mistaken here?

Comment: @PavanManjunath you're mistaken. Buffers are isolated from other processes. A process must flush before other readers can see the data.

Answer (score 2):

Unless my understanding of pipes in completely off the wall, the answer is YES.

Writing to a temp file involves disk access, and the associated overhead.

Writing to a pipe, and reading from it, happens in memory.  Much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I thought a practical answer might help. I'm speed-optimizing a script I use that has about 4 steps.  I set it up to use piping and non-piping methods.  This is under Windows 7 64-bit.

I got a 3% slowdown for not using piping. Which is worth it, for me, because now I can stop between each step and update the window title, which I couldn't when it was all one command.

Personally, I'll take that 3% hit for the window titles.

For curiosity, I am grepping a >20M file, then passing it to a specialized perl script that modifies the results, then sorting them using windows built in SORT.EXE, then uniq'ing them using cygwin's UNIQ.EXE, then re-grepping those same results to get ANSI-based grep-result-coloring. Most of the time is spent in the sorting phase.

Comment: What windows titles are you discussing about? Is this part of the flow you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: Yes, I have some scripts that take a few seconds, so they update the window title of that command-line window to give me something to watch [when minimized] and not get antsy that it might not be doing anything:)

Comment: Note that a sort command is a blocker for concurrency.  It cannot produce any output until it has read all of its input.  Given that and your comment that most of the time is spent in the sort phase, it is not surprising that you got a very small performance change between piped and non-piped control flow.  If your pipeline did not have a blocking sort, you might well demonstrate bigger savings in processing time from the increased concurrency.