# MATLAB : read data file in real time

Tags: matlab

I have an application, A, that writes to a File.
I want to use MATLAB to read N lines in realtime from this file.

My question is related to this stack post: [How to plot real time data from text file in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753403/how-to-plot-real-time-data-from-text-file-in-matlab)

The author of one of the answers, mentions the following approach:

> You can't plot using hard real time conditions, thus it can always happen that matlab misses a 10ms timeslot. You have to use option 2 to get all data.
>
> To get started: Write a function which only reads the new data which was written since last call. To achieve this, do not close the file handle. It stores the position.

As such, here is my code:

```
myfile_fid=fopen(filePath, 'rt')
waitForFileToHaveData(filePath, 10);

for readingIdx = 1:10
    fgetl(myfile_fid)
end
```

My `waitForFileToHaveData` function, is defined as follows:

```
function waitForFileToHaveData(filePath, desired_length)
    if (getNumLinesOfFile(filePath) < desired_length)
        disp('###### not enough data in the file');
        pause(0.02);
        waitForFileToHaveData(filePath, desired_length);
    end
end


function num = getNumLinesOfFile(file_to_read)
    [status, result] = system( ['wc -l ', file_to_read] );
    if(status~=1)
        scanCell = textscan(result,'%u %s');
        num = scanCell{1} - 2;
    else
        num = 0;
    end
end
```

Result:

When I get into the for loop, `myfile_fid` evaluates to `3`, while `fgetl(myfile_fid)` evaluates to `-1`. If I print out the results of `getNumLinesOfFile(filePath)`, I see `20`. The odd part is that if I wait, say for the file to have `40` lines, and execute the code above, I do not get the error. I tried to look at the documentation to see why `fgetl` returns back `-1`, but I cannot seem to find it in 2018b MATLAB documentation. There is mention that the `myfile_fid` can return a `-1`, but that is only if the file cannot be opened. However, at runtime, `myfile_id` evaluates to 3.

Using MATLAB, is it possible to read N number of lines since last read in a file that is being written to by another application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgetl` returns `-1` when `fileID` reaches the **end-of-file** marker, See [Matlab fgetl documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html). This means that if the first result from `fgetl` is `-1` then **the file is empty**.

I'm not sure why you are getting `-1` if `getNumLinesOfFile` returns `20`, check the code carefully if you are reading the same file. Maybe the file has changed?

I wrote here MATLAB code that checks if 10 new lines were added and and then gets them with `fgetl`:

```matlab
myfile_fid = fopen(filePath, 'rt');

newLines = 10;
linesRead = 0;
while(waitForFileToHaveData(filePath, linesRead + newLines))
    linesRead = linesRead + newLines;
    for readingIdx = 1:newLines
        line = fgetl(myfile_fid)
    end
end

fclose(myfile_fid);
```

I updated the `waitForFileToHaveData` function to return `1`:

```matlab
function ready = waitForFileToHaveData(filePath, desired_length)
    while (getNumLinesOfFile(filePath) < desired_length)
        disp('###### not enough data in the file');
        pause(0.02);
    end
    ready = 1;
end
```

**Note:**

If the file had exactly 10 lines with no end-line marker at line 10, and you read them, then another 10 lines were added, `fileID` now points to the end-line of line 10 and the first line `fgetl` will return is the end-line at line 10, but since `fgetl` removes the end-line, it returns an empty array.

**Side note:**

the function `waitForFileToHaveData` uses recursion which is inefficient. You can easily use a while loop.