# Can a text file be updated by two programs simultaneously (live communication)?

Tags: c#, python, c, io, ipc

I have a program that has c/c# abilities, and I have python. I want that program to update a text file, almost in milliseconds, and have the python to read that text file in milliseconds as well. How can I go achieve this?

Is it possible for a text file to be updated live by another program and be read live by python? Is there any alternative way to do this instead of relying on text file. 
Basically what I want to do is a bunch of computations on live data from that program using python and send back those computations to the program in form of commands.Can a file not be closed and reopened and yet updated in the memory?

Comment: I think you want a Pipe instead of a file.

Comment: Adding to what @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen said, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977561/pipe-vs-temporary-file

Comment: I don't think you can achieve "almost" part - the changes will be visible immediately... (Read on share mode for opening files if you really want to go with text file approach - i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222089/in-c-if-2-processes-are-reading-and-writing-to-the-same-file-what-is-the-best)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I edited the question.

Comment: I know that you can establish the pipes if the C part is run from python via a [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) just by specifying `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` (and same for `stdin` and `stderr`) and then you can `.communicate` with it.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen very helpful. a quick search brings up Named Pipes? does it beg its own question or can Named pipes work for my work too?

Comment: is it worthy of an answer? I have no idea how the communications would work from the C# end... Well the same way you would write to the standard out / read from standard in..

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I don't know. I just started reading about pipes after your suggestion, probably will take me a couple of hours to know what is going on and if it suits what I want to do. We'll see.

Comment: I looked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2 and the C# communications look like it would be handled via `System.Console.In` and `System.Console.Out`

Answer (score 0):

If you start the C/C# process from python with `subprocess.Popen` then your two programs can communicate via the `stdin` and `stdout` pipes:

```
c_program = subprocess.Popen(["ARGS","HERE"],
                             stdin = subprocess.PIPE,  # PIPE is actually just -1
                             stdout= subprocess.PIPE,  # it indicates to create a new pipe
                             stderr= subprocess.PIPE  #not necessary but useful
                             )
```

Then you can read the output of the process with:

```
data = c_program.stdout.read(n) #read n bytes
#or read until newine
line = c_program.stdout.readline()
```

Note that both of these are blocking methods, although  [non blocking alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python) exist.

Also note that in python 3 these will return `bytes` objects, you can convert into a `str` with the `.decode()` method.

Then to send input to the process you can simply write to the stdin:

```
c_program.stdin.write(DATA)
```

Like the `read` above, in python 3 this method expects a `bytes` object.  You can use the `str.encode` method to encode it before writing it to the pipe.

---

I have extremely limited knowledge of C# but from limited research it seems that you can [read data from `System.Console.In`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.in(v=vs.110).aspx) and [write data to `System.Console.Out`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.out(v=vs.110).aspx), although if you have written programs in C# that run in a terminal, the same methods used to write data to the screen and read input from the user will work here too. (you can imagine the `.stdout` as the terminal screen and data python writes to `.stdin` the user input)